# Rubbing noise from clutch

Tags: noise, clutch, vauxhall, astra, grinding

Vauxhall  astra sri  2011 reg
When I drive car and it is in gear a grinding rubbing noise happens.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When exactly does the grinding noise occur? Is it when you press the pedal down (to disengage the clutch) or release it up (to engage the clutch)? Or is the noise constant? Is it hard to shift into first or reverse gear at a stop?

Comment: Release  it up to engage the clutch noise starts gear change is ok no hard gear changes